# Datatable datepicker format

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I have a problem with multiple filtering on column start date of my table.
This column is filled with row data formatted as ('dd-mm-yy').
I apply this format to my datepicker but when it try to filtering data on the table it seems to not working.

This is my Javascript code:

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
    function (settings, data, dataIndex) {
        var min = $('#min').datepicker("getDate");
        var max = $('#max').datepicker("getDate");
        var startDate = new Date(data[4]);
        if (min == null && max == null) { return true; }
        if (min == null && startDate <= max) { return true;}
        if(max == null && startDate >= min) {return true;}
        if (startDate <= max && startDate >= min) { return true; }
        return false;
    }
    );


        $("#min").datepicker({ 
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy', onSelect: function () { table.draw(); }, changeMonth: true, changeYear: true  });
        $("#max").datepicker({ 
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',onSelect: function () { table.draw(); }, changeMonth: true, changeYear: true  });
        var table = $('#example').DataTable();

        // Event listener to the two range filtering inputs to redraw on input
        $('#min, #max').change(function () {

            table.draw();
        });
    });
```

This is [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k7a54fL2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `var startDate = new Date(data[4]);` is reading your date as `mm-dd-yyyy` and this brings to invalid dates. Change it to the following line and you are good to go:

```
var startDate = new Date(data[4].substr(6,4), data[4].substr(3,2)-1, data[4].substr(0,2));
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dkorber/m1taq5h9/9/)

Comment: Just keep in mind that months in Java are Zero-based (January is 0, February is 1,...)